# Analytic inverse of $f(z) \neq 0, f(0) = 0, f'(z) \neq 0 $ within minimum modulus on boundary.

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, contour-integration

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on closed disk of radius $r$ and $f(0)=0$, $f'(z) \neq 0$. Show that $f$ has an analytic inverse on $\{|z| \leq m\}$ where $m$ is the minimum of $|f(z)|$ on $\{|z| = r\}$. And

$$f^{-1}(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-u}dz$$

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

$f(z) \neq 0$ for $z \neq 0$, and $\{|u| < m\}$ instead of $\{|z| \leq m\}$.

Comment: This is not true as written. Some further condition is missing (and even then, we could only guarantee an inverse on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < m\}$, not on the closed disk).

Comment: Can you give a counter-example?

Comment: Sure: $$f(z) = z\frac{2z-1}{2-z},$$ with $r = 1$. We have $\lvert f(z)\rvert = 1$ on the boundary $\{z : \lvert z\rvert = 1\}$, but $f$ is not invertible.

Comment: Its derivative has zero at $2-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Oh, I misread the condition as $f'(0) = 0$. Oops.

Comment: Still, if you take $f(z) = e^z - 1$ and $r = 3\pi$, say, it doesn't work as stated. Then $f$ is not injective, hence has no global inverse. It has three local inverses on small disks around $0$, and the value of the given integral is the sum of the values of all three inverses.

Comment: The minimum of $|f|$ on $r = 3\pi$ is $m =0$. $0$ is the only point within disk of radius $m=0$. So $f$ has an inverse at $0$.

Comment: No, the zeros of $f$ are the points $z_k = 2\pi i k,\; k\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $$\min \{ \lvert f(z)\rvert : \lvert z\rvert = 3\pi\} > 0.$$

Comment: $m = min\{|f(z)|: |z| = 3\pi \} < 2\pi$. It is injective inside $m$.

Comment: To deduce the injectivity of $f$ on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < m\}$, you would need $m\leqslant \pi$. But that's irrelevant, the assertion is that $f^{-1}$ is defined on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < m\}$. I don't know what the radius of the largest disk around $0$ on which a branch of $f^{-1}$ is defined is, it could be $m$ or even larger. But in any case, the integral doesn't give a branch of $f^{-1}$; it gives the sum of the three branches of $f^{-1}$ with values in $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < 3\pi\}$ for $u$ in a small enough neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: The assertion becomes correct (with $\lvert z\rvert < m$ instead of $\leqslant m$) if you add a condition that $f(z) \neq 0$ for $z\neq 0$, for example. But you need some further condition, as written, it's incorrect.

Comment: Assuming the conditions you require, can you please show how it's true?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to write an answer, but I'll have to do something else first, will take a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the closed curve $\gamma \colon [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by

$$\gamma(t) = f\bigl(re^{it}\bigr).$$

Since $m = \min \{ \lvert \gamma(t)\rvert : t \in [0,2\pi]\} > 0$, the curve doesn't intersect the disk $\{ u : \lvert u\rvert < m\}$, and therefore the winding number of $\gamma$ around $u$ is constant on that disk. Now, the winding number is

$$n(\gamma,u) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{dw}{w-u} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-u}\,dz,$$

and we recognise the latter as the number of times (counting multiplicity) $f$ attains the value $u$ in the disk $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < r\}$.

By assumption $n(\gamma,0) = 1$, so $n(\gamma,u) = 1$ for $\lvert u\rvert < m$. That is, each value $u$ with $\lvert u\rvert < m$ is attained exactly once on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < r\}$.

Hence the meromorphic function

$$g_u(z) = \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-u}$$

has exactly one singularity in the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < r\}$ for every $u$ with $\lvert u\rvert < m$, and

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-u}\,dz$$

is just the residue of $g$ in $f^{-1}(u)$.

If a holomorphic funtion $h$ attains a value $a$ in $z_0$ with multiplicity $k$, then we can write

$$h(z) = a + (z-z_0)^k\cdot \tilde{h}(z)$$

with a holomorphic function $\tilde{h}$, where $\tilde{h}(z_0) \neq 0$. Then we have

$$\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)-a} = \frac{k(z-z_0)^{k-1}\tilde{h}(z) + (z-z_0)^k\tilde{h}'(z)}{(z-z_0)^k\tilde{h}(z)} = \frac{k}{z-z_0} + \frac{\tilde{h}'(z)}{\tilde{h}(z)},$$

so the residue of $\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)-a}$ in $z_0$ is the multiplicity with which $a$ is attained at $z_0$, and

$$\frac{zh'(z)}{h(z)-a} = \frac{kz}{z-z_0} + \frac{z\tilde{h}'(z)}{\tilde{h}(z)} = \frac{kz_0}{z-z_0} + k + \frac{z\tilde{h}'(z)}{\tilde{h}(z)},$$

so the residue of $\frac{zh'(z)}{h(z)-a}$ in $z_0$ is $k\cdot z_0$.

Here we have $k = 1$ for $\lvert u\rvert < m$, so the residue of $g_u$ in $f^{-1}(u)$ is just $f^{-1}(u)$, and the integral formula

$$f^{-1}(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-u}\,dz$$

is established for $\lvert u\rvert < m$. It holds for all $u$ in the connected component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ \gamma(t) : t\in [0,2\pi]\}$ containing $0$, which usually is strictly larger than the disk $\{u : \lvert u\rvert < m\}$.